# Split array by specific requirements

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am learning to use underscore js. I grouped the array. But now i need split array.

I have a grouped JSON array. For example;

`var arr = [{"key": "A", "value": ["erdem", "metin", "tamer", "hüseyin"]}]`

I want this to be the result.

```
var arr = [{"key" : "A", "value" : "erdem"},{"key" : "A", "value" : "metin"},{"key" : "A", "value" : "tamer"},{"key" : "A", "value" : "hüseyin"}]
```

I'm happy if you show me how to do it.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I could not try because I did not know what to use. If there is any simple example or auxiliary documentation I can do this, I will not hesitate to try. @MarioSantini

Comment: I think you should try with something like: `_.flatten(_.map(yourArr, theSplitFunction), true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@forguta you can use this method to get your required output.

```
var arr = [{"key": "A", "value": ["erdem", "metin", "tamer", "hüseyin"]}]
_.map(arr,function(item){ 
     var temp=[];      
     _.map(item.value, function(x){         
      temp.push({key: item.key, value: x});      
    }); 
  return temp;  
});
```

You can achieve the result without temp variable also (short form)

```
   _.map(arr,function(item){ 
      return _.map(item.value, function(x){
         return {key: item.key, value: x};
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

### Vanilla JS, without *Underscore / lodash* :

```js
var arr = [
  {"key": "A", "value": ["erdem", "metin", "tamer", "hüseyin"]},
  {"key": "B", "value": ["foo", "bar"]}
];

// create modified array of objects
var result = arr.map(item => item.value.map(v => ({ key:item.key, value:v })) );

// print result
console.log( [].concat(...result) );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `reduce` the main array and then `concat` each resulting array with a initial empty array

`arr.reduce((i, o)=>i.concat(o.value.map(v=>({key: o.key, value: v}))), []);`

```js
var arr = [
  {"key": "A", "value": ["erdem", "metin", "tamer", "hüseyin"]},
  {"key": "B", "value": ["foo", "bar"]}
];

var res = arr.reduce((i, o)=>i.concat(o.value.map(v=>({key: o.key, value: v}))), []);

console.log(res);
```